# Ambiguous tag [ps]

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled across this tag description for [ps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps):

> PS can refer either to the UNIX process-information command, or as a file type-extension it refers to the Postscript language created by Adobe Systems.

I don't think it's a good idea to have this kind of ambiguity explicitly in the tag description. For Postscript related questions, there is already [postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postscript). So I'd suggest to change the tag description to exclude Postscript (or maybe hint about the [postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postscript) tag?) and retag postscript questions accordingly. This wouldn't really be a tag disambiguation because all needed tags are already there. What do you think?

Suggestion:

> `ps` is the UNIX command for retreiving process information.
>   For questions about the Postscript language, please use the [postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postscript) tag instead.

---

FYI, I now changed the tag description to be unambiguous and did a lot of re-tagging. Not sure I catched everything, I hope so.

Comment: Just to add into the confusion: `ps` can also refer to `PowerShell`, `Photoshop`, `PlayStation`, `Picosecond `, `Positronium` and [lists of `PS` meanings](https://answi.blogspot.hk/2017/03/what-does-ps-mean-full-forms-of-ps.html)

Comment: At least, for all of these it's an abbreviation -- except for the UNIX `ps` command. That's why I suggest the tag should only refer to that command.

Comment: Correct - Absolutely correct. People always uses short form as their tags, or does not read tag descriptions.

Comment: So you would agree with my suggested course of action? I could go on and retag the questions using [tag:ps] for Postscript (I'll do that if this seems to be consensus here), but I'm not allowed to directly edit the tag description to reflect this.

Comment: I do agree with your suggested tag wiki edit

Comment: This ambiguity is still a problem in 2023.