# Ambiguity reduces the [PV] of this tag to zero

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [pv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pv) tag (32 questions) seems to have been created to address questions associated with the ([`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)) command, and the 5 oldest questions related to this relate to pipe viewer / progress bar questions.  However, more recently, it has lost its specificity.  The questions break down:

- 16 questions (50%) related to the `pv` command, most asking about the [progress-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-bar)
- 9 questions dealing with photovoltaic energy (some also tagged [pvlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pvlib), there's also `SolaR` in R)
- 4 questions dealing with [persistent-volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent-volumes) but not tagged thusly
- 3 questions about Present Value (PV) in finance which need no tag

I'm happy to go through the incorrectly tagged questions and edit them to remove the incorrect tag. I left them for now as evidence of the ambiguity of [pv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pv).  I don't think we need a tag for a particular *nix shell command and to discuss whether to disallow/warn on future use.

I suggest burninating [pv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pv), retagging the questions as outlined in the list above (I am happy to do so if the community approves) and disallowing further use of the tag.

**[Burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071)**:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. Its brevity leads to ambiguity and there are better tags nearly everywhere it's used.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

The on-topic concepts are described in more verbose tags.  A single *nix command by itself is not on topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. The post title nearly always includes more information than the tag would ever provide.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

[No.](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/PV)

---

P.S., See [this related post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353776/ambiguous-tag-ps) regarding the ambiguity of [ps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps).